# SQL Server 2014, 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

My database has this table

```
| Name | Score | Date_time      |
---------------------------------
| A    |  100  | 20200601000000 |
| B    |  120  | 20200615000000 |
| C    |  110  | 20200629000000 |
| B    |  150  | 20200701000000 |
  ...
```

I want get 'Name' and 'Score' by 'Date_time' week day.

Example, when week day is Monday(= 2), I get two data.

```
| A    |  100  |
| B    |  120  |
```

And I tried to use the following sql statement.

```
select Name, Score 
from SCORE_DATA 
where   
datepart(dw, format(cast(Date_time as bigint),'####-##-## ##:##:##')) = 2
```

converting
`20200601000000` to `2020-06-01 00:00:00` and get week day (`dw`) and compare is it 2.

But I get an error:

> 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I can't understand why.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014

It explain `format` function.

Doesn't it apply in SQL Server 2014? What can I do?

Comment: And the compatibility level of your database is...

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts, actually in 2012.

Comment: What does the banner at the top of the page you've linked to say? "The requested page is not available for SQL Server 2014." - that's your clue that the function doesn't exist in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: A better question is why should you mess around with casting and converting and format, when you should simply store date_time as a `DateTime` data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, Gabriele's answer is correct - He is explaining why you're getting the error message you're getting.

However, there is a better way to get your results, that doesn't involve `Format`.

First thing's first: You should seriously consider converting the `[Date_Time]` column you have now from (What I guess based on the code in the question is) a string to a proper `DateTime`.
That will solve not only this specific problem but a bunch of many other problems, some of them you probably have encountered before.
Even if this involves a lot of work it will be worth it in the long run, trust me.

However, considering that's not an option, I would suggest a couple of improvements to your existing code:

1. Use `cast` to convert the first 8 chars directly to a date, instead of converting the entire thing to a bigint and then using format and implicit conversion like your code is attempting to do now.
2. Use `WeekDay` instead of `dw` in the `DatePart` function. It's just more readable.
3. Calculate the week day number based on the `@@DateFirst` value - because SQL Server does exactly that, meaning if someone changes the date first settings your current code will produce the wrong results.

Having said all that, let's see how that looks like in code.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE SCORE_DATA (
  [Name] varchar(1), 
  [Score] int, 
  [Date_time] char(14)
);
    
INSERT INTO SCORE_DATA ([Name], [Score], [Date_time]) VALUES
('A', 100, '20200601000000'),
('B', 120, '20200615000000'),
('C', 110, '20200629000000'),
('B', 150, '20200701000000');
```

The query (with explanatory comments):

```
SELECT  [Name]
      , [Score]
FROM SCORE_DATA
      -- using full name for readability
WHERE (DATEPART(WeekDay, 
                 -- ISO8601 format is unambiguous and will always be converted correctly
                 CAST(
                   -- A string representation of date in ISO8601 Format: yyyyMMdd
                   LEFT([Date_Time], 8) 
                 AS Date) -- You don't need DateTime, just the date...
        -- taking datefirst settings into consideration to get a fixed number
        ) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 = 2
```

Results:

```
Name    Score
A       100
B       120
C       110 -- June 29th 2020 was a Monday too...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your compatibility level as below:

```
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'YourDb';  
GO
```

110 is SQL Server 2012

120 is SQL Server 2014

130 is SQL Server 2016

140 is SQL Server 2017

150 is SQL Server 2019

To change it you can use the following script:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDb
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;  
GO
```

FORMAT function require compatibility level >= 110